# How to set Width for a Widget Spinner in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

How to set Width for a Widget Spinner in GWT

```
Spinner pageNumberSpinner = new Spinner(1, 99999, 1, 1);
```

Please help me to set width to `pageNumberSpinner`.

Comment: Where is `Spinner` from? It doesn't seem to be part of the default API.

Comment: @Baz I think if its a GWT widget then it must extends `UIObject`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
pageNumberSpinner.setWidth("250px");
```

For more info have a look at [UIObject#setWidth()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setWidth%28java.lang.String%29).

Or you can try

```
pageNumberSpinner.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(250, Unit.PX);
```

Or you can try

```
pageNumberSpinner.setStyleName("mycss");
```

css:

```
.mycss{
   width: 250px;
}
```